# Can keyes Sound sensor be used as a Microphone in Raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, linux, python-3, microphone

I am trying to make a speech recognition system on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ using Python. It needs a microphone. I have the keyes Sound sensor which looks like this(https://cutt.ly/Jjp9jWP). Can this sensor be used as a Michrophone?

**Note:- I am very new to raspberry pi so this may sound like a silly question but please give me some knowledge**

Do I need to buy a usb microphone or will this work?

Comment: Ok, This is the link to the datasheet (https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=821a9445-c842-431e-8d50-a83eefcb3e1f&fn=Keyes+Michrophone+Datasheet.pdf&ct=1609863908397&tl=share-document&rf=link)

Comment: Oh, ok. I will try it with the 10k resistor between analog output and Microphone input. I think we can do this with the help of  the potentiometer in the middle?

Comment: If you look at the image link (https://cutt.ly/Jjp9jWP), you'll see a potentiometer in the middle. Can I use that?

Comment: This is the schematic diagram for that (https://cutt.ly/Hjhj24s).. Just scroll down a little bit and also if you want you can read the website as well

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the try tho :)